# developing google actions with google sdk and python flask

Tags: python, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I am developing a google app with actions sdk. I have deployed some sample code without Oauth authentication but I am facing an issue called "401 unauthorized" when I am running the code in my local machine with ngrok as my endpoint and flask as my server.

#!/usr/bin/env python

```
import os
import json

import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.log
import tornado.web

from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google.auth.transport import requests as google_requests

import jwt
import requests
```

## weather api authentication with weather api key

```
API_KEY = os.environ.get('OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_KEY', '9c8a7df55d4c5737a84b7004aacd6d48')
PROJECT_ID = 'zebot'

class WeatherHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def start_conversation (self):
    response = {
      'expectUserResponse': True,
      'expectedInputs': [
        {
          'possibleIntents': {'intent': 'actions.intent.MAIN'},
          'inputPrompt': {
            'richInitialPrompt': {
              'items': [
                {
                  'simpleResponse': {
                    'ssml': '<speak>What city would you like the weather for?</speak>'
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }

    self.set_header("Content-Type", 'application/json')
    self.set_header('Google-Assistant-API-Version', 'v2')
    self.write(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
#parameters
  def get_weather (self, city):
    api_response = requests.get(
      'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather',
      params={'q': city, 'APPID': API_KEY}
    )
    data = api_response.json()
    if 'main' not in data:
      response = {
        'expectUserResponse': False,
        'finalResponse': {
          'richResponse': {
            'items': [
              {
                'simpleResponse': {
                  'ssml': '<speak>City not found - meow!</speak>'
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }

    else:
      temp = round(1.8 * (data['main']['temp'] - 273) + 32)

      response = {
        'expectUserResponse': False,
        'finalResponse': {
          'richResponse': {
            'items': [
              {
                'simpleResponse': {
                  'ssml': '<speak>The temperature in {} is {} degrees.</speak>'.format(city, temp)
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }

    self.set_header("Content-Type", 'application/json')
    self.set_header('Google-Assistant-API-Version', 'v2')
    self.write(json.dumps(response, indent=2))

  def get (self):
    city = self.get_query_argument('city', '')
    if city:
      self.get_weather(city)

    else:
      self.start_conversation()
#jwt decoding and authorization where issue persists
  def post (self):
    print("about to respond")
    token = self.request.headers.get("Authorization")
    print("token",token)
    jwt_data = jwt.decode(token, verify=False)
    print("jwt",jwt_data)
    if jwt_data['aud'] != PROJECT_ID:
      self.set_status(401)
      self.write('Token Mismatch')

    else:
      request = google_requests.Request()
      try:
        # Makes external request, remove if not needed to speed things up
        id_info = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, request, PROJECT_ID)
      except:
        self.set_status(401)
        self.write('Token Mismatch')

    data = json.loads(self.request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    intent = data['inputs'][0]['intent']
    print(intent)
    print(data['conversation']['conversationId'])

    if intent == 'actions.intent.MAIN':
      self.start_conversation()

    else:
      city = data['inputs'][0]['arguments'][0]['textValue']
      self.get_weather(city)

def make_app():
  return tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/weather-app", WeatherHandler),
  ], autoreload=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  tornado.log.enable_pretty_logging()

  app = make_app()
  app.listen(int(os.environ.get('PORT', '8000')))
  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: Can you try directly calling your weather API to see if that works?